# Erlang Build Fails: Can not link the wx driver, wx will NOT be useable

Tags: erlang

`./configure` returns an error message when run:

`wx:Can not link the wx driver, wx will NOT be useable`

When I run `.\configure | grep wx`, the logs are as follows:

```
configure: configuring in wx/.
configure: running /bin/bash '/home/nihal/Downloads/otp_src_17.1/lib/wx/./configure' --prefix=/usr/local  '--prefix=/usr/local' 'ERL_TOP=/home/nihal/Downloads/otp_src_17.1' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/home/nihal/Downloads/otp_src_17.1/lib' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/home/nihal/Downloads/otp_src_17.1/lib/wx/.
rm: remove write-protected regular file './CONF_INFO'? 
checking for debug build of wxWidgets... checking for wx-config... /usr/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.4 (--unicode --debug=yes)... yes (version 2.8.12)
checking for wxWidgets static library... no
checking for standard build of wxWidgets... checking for wx-config... (cached) /usr/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.4 (--unicode --debug=no)... yes (version 2.8.12)
checking for wxWidgets static library... no
checking if wxwidgets have opengl support... yes
checking for wx/stc/stc.h... yes
checking if we can link wxwidgets programs... yes
wx        : Can not link the wx driver, wx will NOT be useable
```

How do I successfully build it?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need `wx`, you can build Erlang without it with:

```
./configure --without-wx
```

If you need `wx` support, see [instructions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html) at `Building with wxErlang` section.

Comment: What will I be missing if I proceed to build without it?

Comment: you be not able to build erlang-based software with wx library, GUI applications

Comment: If you are using the R17, there is no alternative gui library to wx (previously there was gs) so some tools will not be available like observer or debugger without the former alternative for some function (tv for example to inspect tables)

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the $ERL_TOP/lib/wx/config.log file for a possible cause.

In my case, I was missing the c++ compiler. After installing g++ I was able to compile and install OTP with no further problems.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while building erlang on CentOS 7.
I too was missing the C++ compiler.
After doing yum install gcc-c++, I was able to build erlang successfully.